# Read HTTPWebReponse using GetResponseStream readToEnd return strange characters

Tags: c#, streamreader, httpwebresponse

[image: responseFromServer contains strange characters]

we are reading response from HttpWebResponse and the response itself is quite normal, we think.
But when we try to read the string representation of that, we only receive strange characters instead of json formatted normal chars.
Can anyone please tell us what is wrong here? Any question or help is welcomed, if more informations are needed, please comment. Thanks

Comment: Note the response encoding is *gzip*, set `request.AutomaticDecompression` accordingly to enable decompression.

Comment: cool! that works, please write that as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response content encoding header is *gzip* indicating the content has been compressed by the server.

Set `request.AutomaticDecompression` to tell the `HttpWebResponse` you want it to decompress the data automatically.