# I can not Parse JSON to string

Tags: c#, json, string, parsing, url

I have problem with my C# code. I don't know how to fix. I just want to get all title from json.
It showed error at:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(jsons);
```

> "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line
>   0, position 0."

```
public void getTitle()
{
    ArrayList myTitle = new ArrayList();
    string url = "https://www.fiverr.com/gigs/endless_page_as_json?host=subcategory&type=endless_auto&category_id=3&sub_category_id=154&limit=48&filter=auto&use_single_query=true&page=1&instart_disable_injection=true";
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var jsons = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        if (jsons != null)
        {
            var obj = JObject.Parse(jsons);
            var urll = (string)obj["gigs"]["title"];
            myNode1.Add(urll);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("nothing");
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: Swow waht value has `var jsons`.

Comment: When you open the website directly, it automatically downloads a file with the desired JSON in it. What you want is to parse the JSON that's inside this file and not the source code of the website.

Comment: You need to decompress gzip content (that's what you are getting from url), you can do it using WebRequest and setting AutomaticDecompression property of it to DecompressionMethods.GZip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080674/read-httpwebreponse-using-getresponsestream-readtoend-return-strange-characters

Comment: Following namespaces need to be imported to make this code compilable: 
`using System.Collections;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net;`

Answer (score 2):

`WebClient` class will be of no help in this case as the data being returned is in gZip compression format. The point of confusion is that when the same URL is browsed in a browser it shows plain text, as the task of decompression is performed automatically by the browser itself.

Following code snippet should solve your problem. Also the array index was missing before you access title property:

```
public void getTitle()
{
    ArrayList myTitle = new ArrayList();
    string url = "https://www.fiverr.com/gigs/endless_page_as_json?host=subcategory&type=endless_auto&category_id=3&sub_category_id=154&limit=48&filter=auto&use_single_query=true&page=1&instart_disable_injection=true";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)))
    {
        var jsons = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (jsons != null)
        {
            var obj = JObject.Parse(jsons);
            var urll = (string)(obj["gigs"][0]["title"]); //returns: design a Tshirt for you        
        }
    }
}
```